# BaseGameUtils / GameHelper onSignInFailed and onSignInSucceeded both called?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

I found a problem with my Google Play Game Sign-in during Alpha testing.  It only happens when the user has an incorrectly cached password for their Google Play login.

Here is what I mean....

When sign in is initiated, it attempts to sign in and the then displays this:

[image]

So far, so good. If we then hit 'Try Again', we get this....

[image]

Still all good.  However, if we type in our password.  A strange thing happens,  once you type it and press 'Sign in', it does sign in successfully, however the following callbacks are called (in the order they appear)

- **onSignInFailed**

then

- **onSignInSucceeded**

Why?  Is this a bug in GameHelper/BaseGameUtils? Is there any way around it?  I can't figure out, why when successfuly logging in, it would call onSignInFailed()!